# Redirect to index.html in a Multi store

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

For our multistore we want to redirect one of the domains to a index.html page during the development. I know normally you can do the rewriterule to index.html in your .htacces and you can redirect a non www to a www with:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

We have made the index.html page and the live webshop is up and running for the second domain (so a different url) we want to make a rule like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/index.html$1 [R=301,L]
```

if we us the code above we end up with a domain looking like: http://www.domain.com/index.htmlindex.php

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 2nd rule to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/index.html [R=301,L]
```